# Batch Normalization as the Final Layer

Tags: batch-normalization, network-design

In [this community implementation](https://github.com/timesler/facenet-pytorch/blob/fa70227bd5f02209512f60bd10e7e66877fdb4f6/models/inception_resnet_v1.py#L258) of [Inception-ResNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07261.pdf), [Batch Normalization](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/ioffe15.pdf) is used as the final layer.

This is unlikely to be a mistake, but also seems counterintuitive. The [inceptionv2 paper](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Szegedy_Rethinking_the_Inception_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf) suggests that Batch Normalization acts as a regularizer. But wouldn't it be too strong of a regularizer as the very last layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regularization effect of Batch Normalization (BN) is a *side effect*, since it introduces noise during training because it uses batch statistics (first and second moments) to normalize the data.

I guess that, in the implementation that you have seen, BN is used as the last layer just to provide an output that approximately follows a Gaussian distribution (that can be 0-mean and unitary variance, for example), and so on for the purpose of regularization.

Comment: 1. Why does it cause the output to approximately follow a Gaussian distribution?

Comment: 2. Why is it useful for the output to approximately follow a Gaussian distribution?

Comment: 1) Because BN standardizes the batch, by subtracting mean and dividing by variance. So it's like transforming the data to be Gaussian-like. Then, it scales and shifts them to provide more flexibility as a 0-mean 1-variance normal can be too restrictive. 2) It can be due to the data be normalized in the same way, but also to ensure better convergence given a specific loss function, or even to comply to some theoretical property of the problem (but that is beyond Inception I guess.)